# Unwanted opening Xfce4 Terminal after login

Tags: debian, terminal, login, xfce

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) with Xfce4 as Desktop Environment. Every time I login into Xfce, three instances with different widths and heights, of the xfce-terminal are getting opened. This behavior is unwanted. Which files are responsible for the login into xfce4 and could be reviewed for possible errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run `xfce4-settings-manager`, either from a terminal or a menu (e.g. on a Debian system running xfce, it's the first item `Settings Manager` in the `Settings` sub-menu of the Debian menu).

   The same sub-menu should also have a `Setting and Startup` item which you can select directly instead of hunting for the icon in step 2 below.
2. Click on the `Session and Startup` icon.  For the current version (xfce4 4.16.0-1) on my system, the icon is a cartoonish retro-SF rocketship on a blue background for some unfathomable reason. This may vary on your system, UI hieroglyphics never make any sense and change according to whim.
3. Make sure that `Automatically save session on logout` is **unchecked** in the `General` tab
4. Click on the `Saved Sessions` tab.
5. Click on the `Clear Saved Sessions` button
6. You might also want to review the `Application Autostart` and `Advanced` tabs.  Good luck finding any documentation on what the items in these tabs actually mean or do. You're supposed to just magically know or guess, I suppose.

---

BTW, if you're happy messing around with xfce4's XML config files (with inadequately-documented effects on the behaviour of xfce, as is traditional), you can snoop around in `~/.config/xfce4/`, probably `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml`. You probably need to edit the session with the name "Default" (search for `<property name="SessionName" type="string" value="Default"/>`)

Comment: I have been messing around with the xfce4-setting-manager and checked "Display chooser on login" under the first tab and topic "session chooser". I do not understand how this works but after a reboot, I login into a clear screen.

Comment: Thnx for that useful solution. I had the same problem with that wretched drop-down terminal opening each time I logged in to Mint. The first place I looked was in Session And Startiup, but nothing of relevance seen in there.There is nothing out there on Google, nor anything in the Xfce documentation about this issue, nor about clearing Saved Sessions. All news to me.